# Tutorial on the life-cycle of a forked GIT repository while using remote tags

Tags: git, tags, fork

### Disclaimer

I'm a bit new to GIT so please excuse me if I have this ting entirely wrong. I've been using Subversion for a very long time and see the huge benefits of GIT and am actively trying to make the switch. However, I've come up with this issue which I can't seem to find a good tutorial or how-to on.  That is the proper use of upstream tags.

### What I've Done

My example is with github.com hosted repository, redmine. It contains many tags for stable releases and branches and a current running master.

I've forked it on my own system by issuing

```
cd /srv/git-repos
git clone --mirror https://github.com/redmine/redmine.git redmine.git
```

I've then cloned my local fork by doing the following

```
cd /opt
git clone /srv/git-repos/redmine.git
```

Then I followed the github.com instructions of adding a remote upstream by

```
cd /opt/redmine
git remote add upstream https://github.com/redmine/redmine.git
```

Cool, at this point I have a forked copy of the redmine on my system which I can commit and push and pull from. I also have added the real redmine as upstream which I can also pull from.

So the first thing I want to do is get this new repo at the state that my current install is running.

Seems easy enough:

```
# Checkout the older tag I'm on
git checkout v1.1.0

# Add a plugin as a submodule
git submodule add git://github.com/delaitre/redmine_time_tracker.git vendor/plugins/redmine_time_tracker
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Now I want to commit this to my fork (I'm pretty sure I've already gone wrong)

```
git commit -m 'Added a new submodule'
```

### Where I'm At

Awesome! I'm now back where I started from not using git, but everything is versioned and safe and hopefully easier to manage.

### The problem

The whole point of this is I wanted to be safe before upgrading to a new version (v1.4.0) which is a tag upstream.

So, how do I switch to the new tag on upstream while keeping the commits I've made to my local fork?

I said above (I think I already went wrong). From some additional reading I think I should have branched the remote tag some how and been committing to a new branch based off the remote tag. This is because I'm sure right now I'm in a "detached HEAD state" which is apparently bad.

### Looking For

1. How do I branch from a tag.
2. What is the best practice for naming this "branched tag" (e.g. _v1.2.0 , my_v1.2.0, local_v1.2.0)

   - Am I being overly anal and who gives a crap what it's named?
3. **Next Step**: How do I merge in the new remote tag (i.e. v1.4.0)
4. How do I commit this new merged in tag, etc.

### Conclusion

Am I completely off base, nuts, flat-out wrong, or missing the point? Is this an uncommon scenario? Am I missing out on documentation on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I branch from a tag.

git checkout -b newBranch yourTag

Note that:

- `git clone --mirror https://github.com/redmine/redmine` is enough (no need to mention the .git, and that will create a "redmine' directory, instead or readmine.git directory, which is a naming convention reserved for bare repo)
- `git checkout aTag` will leave you in a **[detached HEAD mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714)**, which means, at this point, you need to create a new branch:

```
git checkout aNewBranch
```

That will create it from your current commit (which isn't attached to any branch right now).
And beware of submodules: they themselves are checked out in a detached HEAD mode: see "[How to make submodule with detached HEAD to be attached to actual HEAD?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8644339/6309)" and "[How do I get `git clone --recursive` to recreate submodules' remotes and branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666085/how-do-i-get-git-clone-recursive-to-recreate-submodules-remotes-and-branche/11451714#11451714)"

Comment: The reason I had done redmine.git is for two reasons, one being that it's already in a project directory named that. This was to signify that it was the repo directory. Two, is because I thought by doing **clone --mirror** that I was essentially creating a bare directory.  More importantly, is that checkout -b branching a remote tag or local tag, or does it not matter?  My big issue is I'm taking a remote tag, I suppose branching it, and then turning it into a local tag based off the remote.

Comment: @StephenOstrow No, `git clone --mirror` isn't for bare repo. Only the `--bare` option creates a bare repo. `xxx.git` directories are for bare repo '`xxx`'. `git checkout -b` is about creating a new *local* branch from a *starting point*. That starting point can be another local branch or tag, or it can be a remote branch (one beginning with the name of a remote, like `origin/aBranch`)