# Can I mark submodule to use different then master branch by default

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules, git-clone

I have fork of a repo as submodule and I have separated branch (that is pull request BTW) and I want my repo to use that feature branch as default for submodule so people that clone my repo will use that feature branch. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so: a submodule is there to record a specific commit to be reused.

Other users cloning your repo will update that submodule at that same commit SHA1 ([in a detached HEAD mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714)), they won't see a branch.
This is what is explained in:

- "[Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/git-submodules-specify-a-branch-tag)".
- "[how exactly does git submodule work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078365/how-exactly-does-git-submodule-work/12078816#12078816)"
- "[How to make submodule with detached HEAD to be attached to actual HEAD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642668/how-to-make-submodule-with-detached-head-to-be-attached-to-actual-head/8644339#8644339)"

Once updated, a user can go into that submodule, checkout a branch and link it to a remote tracking branch of the corresponding remote repo for that submodule if he/she wants.
But once the modifications are done, that branch won't be part of the submodule information recorded by the parent repo.