# When I git clone something, and then commit it, it does not show up in my repository?

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have a "javascript" directory. I `git clone http:...` a plugin inside that javascript directory.

Then, I `git add .`

And I finally `git commit -am 'message'`; and `git push origin master`

When I go to github.com, I see that the plugin is not there as a folder! Instead, there's a folder with an arrow to it, probably symbolizing that it's a link to another plugin.

How do I add stuff that I cloned into my OWN repository?

Edit: I just read about submodules, but they're a pain in the ass! How do I easily manage them?

Comment: http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, rather than cloning a Git repo within a Git repo (which would mean dealing with a submodule declaration in order for the parent repo to reference the second inner repo), would be to merge the two repo: **[subtree merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632540/merge-2-same-repository-git/8634609#8634609)**.
That is interesting when the two repos are closely linked together (an evolution in one is likely to trigger an evolution in the other).

The various possibility to deal with two repos are presented in "[How do you merge two git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories/1426163#1426163)".