# Using Git: Integrating a fork into another repository while keeping it separate

Tags: git, fork

I have this project and I'm using github for the first time. My question is regarding forks. My problem is that I want to fork this code I saw in github but I also want to use it in my existing project and work on the fork from there. Do I download the files then integrate it into my project

```
git add foldername/
git commit -m 'Added some awesome code from github'
git push -u origin master
```

or is there a way to retain it as a fork but have it as a *branch* in my repository? Or am I talking crazy here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution would be closer to the [subtree merge](http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html), which is great if the two repos are closely linked together and can now evolve within *one* repo.

But you want to contribute back to your fork, in order to make some pull request back to the original project.
As three said in the comments, [git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1979194/6309) are more appropriate, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8634609/6309):
For two different sets of files with different history and different pace in their evolutions (commits), you can reference your fork within your main project as a submodule.